# Bootstrap 3 glyphicons in add ons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bellow is my html (in Jade) of glyphicons in add ons.

```
.input-group
    input.form-control(type='text')
    span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar
```

However the addon is not aligned with the input field. Screeshot:

[image]

Is it normal or a bug in bootstrap 3?

**Update**

Got it: 
in bootstrap.css:2171 (compiled with less)

```
.glyphicon{ ...; top: 1px; ...}
```

Bug?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the zoom level of your browser (ctrl+0 in Firefox)?

Comment: @JasonSperske hmm no it's in default. In all levels they appear like that. Btw this is Chrome OS X, but also replicates in safari.

Comment: It would help if you'd show your HTML. Maybe there's something going on outside those elements. Show the whole form.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<strike>Yes, it seems a bug for my:</strike> It's a bug: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10936

I read this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9850 first.

I use this code to this:

```
<div class="container"> 
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>    
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>    
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>    
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">   
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>    
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>    
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>    
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></span>    
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

Results for Firefox:

[image]:

There will be a problem for `input-group-lg` the double span makes the input longer (due to .glyphicon:empty) but didn't fix the problem.
I also not found `.glyphicon{ ...; top: 1px; ...}` caused this problem.

For firefox i found this solution:

from bootstrap.css:

```
.input-group-lg > .form-control,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-addon,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-btn > .btn {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Changing the vertical padding from 10px to 9px solved the issue.

This css rules comes from forms.less (.input-lg() call from inputgroups.less)
using @padding-large-vertical:         10px; (from variables.less)

In google chrome i found a same kind of problem, for all sizes see:

[image]

In this case it helps to use the double span:

```
`<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></span>`
```

Comment: Hi Bass, thanks. I solved it by disabling the 23rd line [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/glyphicons.less). I don't know why it exists but it's the only thing that seems to create the trouble.

Answer (score 42):

To clarify Bass' answer, with the current version of Bootstrap 3, all you need to do is:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></span>
</div>
```

In other words, just the basic Bootstrap markup as described in the docs.

Comment: The key is to nest <span> with .glyphicon inside <span> with .input-group-addon. Using a single <span> with both .glyphicon and .input-group-addon as in OP's example may cause trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Local override:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .glyphicon {
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
    <span class="add-on"> <i class="icon-user"></i></span>
    <input class="span2" id="appendedPrependedInput" type="text">
    <span class="add-on"> <i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with

`.glyphicon{
  line-height: 1em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

within the button place the html code '&nbsp'

&nbsp

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-color"></i></span>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this "position: initial" to the span style that the glyphicon lives in. OR you  could use css like this.

```
.glyphicon {
  position: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-tags" style="position:initial"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tags" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but it might help someone: I use a button and it works perfectly!

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></button>
        </span>                        
    </div>
```