# glyphicon input field from Bootstrap not aligned

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I am combining Angular with Bootstrap and when putting a glyphicon next to a search input field, the upper border doesn't seem aligned.

```
div.input-group(ng-show='feeds.length > 0')
   span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
   input.form-control(type='text', data-ng-model='filterText')
```

What are the modifications to the CSS (or other) that are needed to align their top borders?

See Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBSxf/

Comment: You can clearly see in the jsfiddle example that the top and bottom of the glyphocon and the input box are not aligned with each other

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [Bootstrap 3 glyphicons in add ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168550/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-in-add-ons)
Changing the code to:

```
div.input-group(ng-show='feeds.length > 0')
   span.input-group-addon
       span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
   input.form-control(type='text', data-ng-model='filterText')
```

it did the trick.